# Identity server 4.o with JWT using .pfx certificate example code

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

Could you share the sample code of identityserver4.0 in getting JWT token using pfx certificate. How to set apisources in in IdentityServer? How to call from api

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear by saying "Getting JWT token using pfx certificate". What are you trying to solve? If you mean how to sign requests with pfx certificate take a look at this [link](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers). Might be an overkill, otherwise I am not sure what are you really trying to achieve here. Look at Identity API project from this solution, it will give you an idea how to utilize IdentityServer4 not just for signing using pfx but in general how it is utilized.